# To calculate euclidean distance between vectors in a torch tensor with multiple dimensions

Tags: pytorch, tensor

There is a random initialized torch tensor of the shape as below.

**Inputs**

```
tensor1 = torch.rand((4,2,3,100))
tensor2 = torch.rand((4,2,3,100))
```

`tensor1` and `tensor2` are torch tensors with 24 100-dimensional vectors, respectively.

I want to get a tensor with a shape of `torch.size([4,2,3])` by obtaining the Euclidean distance between vectors with the same index of two tensors.

I used `dist = torch.nn.functional.pairwise_distance(tensor1, tensor2)` to get the results I wanted.

However, the `pairwise_distance` function calculates the euclidean distance for the second dimension of the tensor. So `dist` shape is `torch.size([4,3,100])`.

I have performed transpose several times to solve these problems. My code is as follows.

```
tensor1 = tensor1.transpose(1,3)
tensor2 = tensor2.transpose(1,3)
dist = torch.nn.functional.pairwise_distance(tensor1, tensor2)
dist = dist.transpose(1,2)
```

Is there a simpler or easier way to get the result I want?

Comment: [torch.cdist](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.cdist.html) is also an option.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here ya go

```
dist = (tensor1 - tensor2).pow(2).sum(3).sqrt()
```

Basically that's what Euclidean distance is.

Subtract -> power by 2 -> sum along the unfortunate axis you want to eliminate-> square root

Answer (score 1):

To use pytorch for all operations (might yield faster solutions):

```
distance = torch.sqrt(torch.sum(torch.pow(torch.subtract(a, b), 2), dim=0))
```